# How to plot a 2*2 grid of images using pyplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to generate a grid style plot of the images of cifar-10 data set. My code:

```
#load the data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
for i in range(0, 8):
    pyplot.subplot(440 + 1 + (i))
    pyplot.imshow(toimage(X_train[i]))
pyplot.show()
```

which works fine for all grids of size 3*3 and more but throws the following error if I replace `440` with `220` or `110`:

> File "main.py", line 24, in 
>       pyplot.subplot(220 + 1 + (i))   File "/root/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 1044, in subplot
>       a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)   File "/root/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py",
>   line 1020, in add_subplot
>       a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/root/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py",
>   line 64, in **init**
>       maxn=rows*cols, num=num)) ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5

I read the previous answers on this topic but somehow, couldn't figure it out. What could be the possible reason? And how do I plot a 2*2 grid of images?

Comment: If you look at the error, `ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5`, apparently your code tries to draw a fifth subplot. In general, it's more useful if you post your non-working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of `pyplot.subplot(nmk)` means that you have an `n`x`m` grid of `n*m` subplots and select the `k`th subplot of those. This implies that `k` cannot be larger than `n*m`.

This is given for `441 + k` with `k` ranging between `0` to `7`, since `4*4 = 16`. However, it is not true anymore for `221`.
The highest `k` you can choose for a `2`x`2` grid is `4`, so your loop needs to be:

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    pyplot.subplot(221 + (i))
```

A `1`x`1` grid does not have more than one plot, so using a loop there is pointless and the only possible plot is `pyplot.subplot(111)`.

Comment: `fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(2, 2)` is probably a better option here, the 'specify-axes-via-3-digit-number' is an API inherited from matlab we would like to de-emphasize